What does 'do not trade' mean?
What does do not trade mean? I'm trying to pull a list of members who have 'opted out' of sending their info to sponsors.

The Answer below is correct - but in more general terms I suspect it is a field that gets very little usage, and I know others have repurposed it for other needs.

Here is a brief explanation of each of the privacy options in the CiviCRM contact record:
Do not phone - The end user has elected to not be contacted via telephone.
Do not email - The end user has elected to not be contacted via email.
Do not mail - The end user has elected to not be contacted via postal delivery (snail mail)
Do not SMS - The end user has elected to not be contacted via text messaging service to their mobile device.
Do no trade - The user has elected not to share their info with other organizations. (ie. you may not share or sell user's information to other parties)
NO BULK EMAILS (User Opt Out) - This is set when a user selects the Opt Out action in a CiviMail Email.
